# How to force columns to wrap inside a band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have spent a couple of days at least trying to get this to work, with no success.  I have a master report with multiple subreports.  One of the
subreports gets data from a list, which has its own SQL query.  Everything works as far as the connection, passing parameters, etc.
The subreport is set up to use 5 columns.  Each column is a small image and a text field.  Again, this data comes through fine.  If
I run the subreport standalone, it looks pretty good, i.e., the data is correct and I also get the columns.

When I run the master report, however, the subreport in question will start to print at the bottom of one page, and the columns
kick in, but since it usually spills over to a new page, on the new page the first column goes all the way down the page.

What I really want I am starting to fear I cannot do, namely, force the entire subreport data to be in a "box" that will cause
there to be 5 columns.

I tried putting everything in a frame, hoping that would "force" what I wanted, but it will not.

It seems almost like that using columns to get the particular look I want (I am trying to duplicate another Access report)
may not be possible.  While the data does not change much, I still think using a dynamic list is the right way to go.  I just
want to force it inside a box where it will always wrap to 5 columns.

I have tried every combination of stretch type and band parameters, based on many Google searches, but 
cannot make this work.

Am I simply on the wrong track?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I attached a screen shot from
what the subreport looks like stand-alone, which is good, but it will not print this way from the master report.

Comment: The attachment did not come through I'm afraid.

Are you trying to force the Subreport to be in a Subreport-element that is smaller than its page width-height?

If child report has a page width and height of 100x100, but your parent report has a subreport element of 50x100, then you will have problems.  Even being 1px off will cause the kind of issues you are seeing.

A screenshot will help.

Comment: Interesting idea... It is pretty confusing to understand exactly how all of the various band heights, splitting, stretching, etc. work together to form the final layout.  The subreport is in detail band 4 of the main report... its band height is 60.  The subreport itself has a page height of 250 and width of 612.  I will try playing around with these values.

Comment: You may want to play around with a test project that mimics what you are doing, but with basic filled-in color rectangles.  I've found that this helps to "visualize" the areas that the report generates and handles.